# Навигационное меню

Tags: html, bootstrap

Есть навигация по сайту:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#176">test</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#110">test</a></li>                          
</ul>
```

и потом `tab-content`.
По нажатию на ссылку из списка, справа появляется соответствующий контент.
Как сделать, чтобы если в адресной строке человек ввел якорь  `#110`, то добавился класс `active` к второму `<li>` и также к этому контенту?
Возможно ли это сделать средствами Bootstrap?

Answer (score 2):

Думаю можно как-то так:

Добавить в ul id = 'nav' и прописать где-то скриптик:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var hash = window.location.hash;
  if(hash)
    $('#nav a[href="#'+hash+'"]').tab('show');
});
```

PS: Должен быть подключен bootstrap-tab.js или bootstrap.js